# img is blocking hover function to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need some help with the following:
i have a an image placed in my body which has a hover function

```
<div id="wrapper">
<img style="position: absolute;" src="img/image.png" name="man" width="150" id="man_1" />
</div>

 $("#man_1").hover(function () {
     $('#wrapper').append('<img id="hoverimg" src="bla.png">');
     console.log("enter mouser");
 },function () {
     $('#hoverimg').remove();
     console.log("leave mouse");
 });
```

as you can see when im hovering the image, it appends another image which has the same top and left values as `#man_1`. The problem is, that when im leaving the mouse the remove does not fire because the mouse is actually on the new hoverimg

hope you get my point! Thanks

Comment: What about adding a mouseleave handler to the new image and removing it? Or changing the src attribute of the old image instead of adding a new one?

Comment: thanks for that point, thats how i made it before. but i need a second image, thats why i was asking!

Comment: mmm whats the expected behavior, i think it works for me :/ http://jsfiddle.net/orlando/pEzWJ/

Comment: this works because the appended image is behind the one who is hovered. change the z-index and you will see it wont work without flickering! thanks anyways for your effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/TXrWP/1/)**</kbd>

Maybe with another markup, it be easier to to this:

### HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="photo">
        <div class="image"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/220" /></div>
        <div class="size"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x40" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.photo {
    position: relative;
    height: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}

.photo .image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}


.photo .size {
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
    transition: margin-bottom 0.3s;
}

.photo .size.show {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

### JS

```
$(function () {
    $('.photo')
        .on('mouseenter', function () {
            $(this).find('.size').addClass('show');
        })
        .on('mouseleave', function () {
            $(this).find('.size').removeClass('show');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the mouseenter and mouseout events

```
$("#man_1").mouseenter(
        function() {
            $('#wrapper').append('<img id="hoverimg" src="bla.png">');
            console.log("enter mouser");
        });
$('#hoverimg').mouseout(
        function() {
           $('#hoverimg').remove();
            console.log("leave mouse");
        }                         
    );
```

Comment: I think you mean `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`?

Comment: #man_1 is an img and cant contain another element. So then you can use both. see http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/different-between-mouseout-and-mouseleave-in-jquery/

Comment: that should be the answer. i will check that in a few minutes!

Answer (score 1):

What if you bind the `hover` event to the `#wrapper` instead?

That works, in this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnrjg/).

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/43/

```
<div class="out overout">
    <img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSuTs4RdrlAhxd-qgbGe9r0MGB9BgwFrHDvfr9vORTBEjIYnSQ8hg" />
</div>

  $("div.overout").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).append("<img src='http://files.softicons.com/download/system-icons/apple-logo-icons-by-thvg/png/512/Apple%20logo%20icon%20-%20Classic.png' id='hovering'/>")
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $('#hovering').remove();
  });
```

I used `mouseover` and `mouseout` instead of `hover`.

I understood as you want to show both images on mouseover and remove the added image on mouseout. Is that correct or not?